# How to decide a type of GetMapping method in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm spring boot learner and trying to clone-code a website. Below is a code to get a data of the specific content.

```
 @GetMapping("/api/articles/{id}")
    public List<Article> takeArticle() { return articleRepository.findAllByOrderByModifiedAtDesc();}
```

Then the ARC shows whole data of contents which I've already posted, but I want a specific data according to the id value. I think the problem is the type of takeArticle() method. So which type should be used for the method above to fulfill my purpose?

Comment: you can research with @PathVariable in spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/api/articles/{id}")
public Article takeArticle(@PathVariable Integer id) { 
  
  return articleRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
      // throw Not found exception if article doesn't exists with given id
  });
}
```

By the way you shouldn't use repository interfaces directly in your controller layer. Use service layer between repository and controllers.